# VB6 - IIF (ISNULL(rs),"TRUE",Replace())

Tags: vb6, recordset

why i cannot use :

```
     rep8_bc = IIf(IsNull(rs(8)), "null", Replace(rs(8), "'", "''"))
```

it say " Invalid use of Null"

but if i remove replace, it's work. And then get error because record have an apostrophe character, so i change the code into this :

```
 rep8_bc = "null"
 If IsNull(rs(8)) = False Then rep8_bc = Replace(rs(8), "'", "''")
```

or this :

```
 If IsNull(rs(8)) = False Then
     rep8_bc = Replace(rs(8), "'", "''")
 else
     rep8_bc = "null"
 end if
```

Comment: So you're trying to achieve what?

Comment: Use .Net instead ;) I can not compile VB6 on my system, as I do not have the tools installed. I am not familiar with the inline if-statement of VB6. But the syntax looks ok to me

Comment: alright.. this is so old.. :P
just asking, maybe someone know the answer hehehe... xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly likely compiler doesn't short circuit within IIF() statement. Compiler takes it as a whole statment (both values) before returning one. That's where you get the error. So breaking into pieces of proper conditional statemetns would be the key here. So you have any achieved that with your answer.
To further add, IIF() is much *slower* in execution than the IF-ELSE statments.

Comment: in my answer have 2 way for running, which one is better? "1. insert null then check if", or "if , else?" .. first for save my line... xD

Comment: In your case, single line IF and multi-line IF both stay at relatively same speed. Unless you have some other operators(arithmatic etc) in one answer and not in the other. Then the IF statement with additional math operator seem to take more time/resources. [Check this post out](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/not-optimize.html)

Comment: Correct, `IIf` does not short-circuit (in [VB6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445024(v=vs.60).aspx) or VB.Net).