# VBA in query error evaluating false part of IIF

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have the following column in a query.

```
iif(Len([Field1])=0,0,Asc(Mid([Field1] & "",Len([Field1]))))
```

The idea is that it should return the ASCII value of the last character in a string field.
The problem is that if Field1 is blank the statement errors with the following message: "Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)". If the field is blank it should return 0.

Comment: Well don't forget that at times complier [doesn't short circuit within IIF() statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357344/vb6-iif-isnullrs-true-replace/13357439#13357439). So in your case evaluate `field1` to be not null...

Comment: @bonCodigo You're correct for `IIf()` in VBA code.  However `IIf()` *does* short-circuit when used in a query.

Comment: @HansUp agreed with you. Rick if your `IIF()` gonna get overly long, then you may want to consider a `UDF` with `case`...relatively fast and keep clarity of your query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming blank means either Null or an empty string, you can concatenate an empty string to `[Field1]`, and if the combined length is 0, return 0.

The `Right()` function is more direct than `Mid()` to get the last character.

```
SELECT IIf(Len([Field1] & "")=0,0,Asc(Right([Field1],1)))
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

By all means you have HansUp's answer to go ahead. :)

..At any point of this *querying voyage*, your query with `IIF` gets very very long... ;) here a head start with a `UDfunction` that uses **`REGEX`**. In your case the most important aspect is to validate the input - not much of getting the `ASCII` value. Since your concern mainly on last `character`, what if your Field1 contains `alphanumeric` value and if your last character happens to be `digit`, `special character` instead of `String`. Well, just to be safe, we could validate that in the following funciton which will respond **only to `Strings`**. Another advantage is that you can re-use this function within your db.

Perhaps this really is **complicating** your process :D

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit 

 Public Function GetASCII(strField1 As String) As Integer 
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim strTemp As String

    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    '--assume strField1 = "hola", you may enter different types 
    '-- of values to test e.g. "hola1, hola$ , hola;

    With regex
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+"

        '--check for null
        Select Case IsNull(strField1) '-- validates any other datatype than String
            Case True
                GetASCII = 0
            Case Else
                Select Case IsError(strField1)
                   Case True
                      GetASCII = 0
                   Case Else
                      Select Case IsEmpty(strField1)
                          Case True
                             GetASCII = 0
                             '--check if entire string is String 
                             '--only (no special characters, digits)
                             '--you may change this to only check the 
                             '----last character if your Field1 is alphanumeric
                          Case Else
                             Select Case .Test(strField1)
                                 Case True
                                    strTemp = Mid(strField1, Len(strField1), 1)
                                    GetASCII = Asc(strTemp)
                                 Case Else
                                    GetASCII = 0
                             End Select
                      End Select        
                End Select        
        End Select        
    End With            
    Set regex = Nothing
 End Function
```

Note: Thought this would be helpful in the long run :) An [Access Query Primer Article](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html).

Comment: @Rick one of these days if you need to use a funciton, you may check this answer out ;) and even get it customized or improved accordingly.

Comment: You declared strField1 As String. A string can never be Null, so this part of the function is not useful: '--check for null</br> Select Case IsNull(strField1)

Comment: @HansUp you may add `Dim strNull as String` , don't assign a value; and use that String variable within the `Select case IsNull(strNull)`. It returns true for null. So in VBA Excel, Access you can have null for Strings it seems.... I have also mentioned that in anycase if the `Field1` happens to be contain a `alphanumeric` or perhaps a `numeric`.

Comment: Rick said he wants "*the ASCII value of the last character in a string field*" ... a **string** field.  Don't re-define his question just to make your answer fit.  ;-)

Comment: No, strNull can not contain Null when declared as string. If you try this assignment, you will trigger error #94, '*Invalid use of Null*'
: strNull = Null

Comment: @HansUp my comment says **, don't assign a value**. So why do you assign null? just show an error? ;) Coz I wouldn't know why one would want to assign NULL in the first place...

Comment: I tried to help you see a VBA string variable can never contain Null.  If you declare `strNull` as string, it will be initialized as an empty string ("") not a Null.  If you don't assign anything, `strNull` will remain "".  So `IsNull(strNull)` will be equivalent to `IsNull("")` ... and will return False.  A VBA string variable can never contain Null under any circumstances.

Comment: @HansUp I thank you for explaining things here :) And I had no time to get back earlier. The puzzle I had, because there was no `deliberate null` assinging in the code. I ran the code by pointing to a random cell with no values(literally empty), and for `IsNull()` it reutnrs `false`... for `IsEmpty()` it reuturns `false`. So I agree with you. But I would still want to keep `IsNull` for other data types, in anycase the user happens to enter one other than a `String`. You see my answer is not posted to compete with yours. It was an alternative, in the event `IIF` are train like long :)